# Meaning of w3wp.exe: All outstanding func-evals have not completed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, w3wp.exe

In my years of using Visual Studio and attaching and detaching from processes, I can't recollect seeing this error, which is why it stood out to me just now when I detached from an IIS .NET 4.0 website project.

I'm purely curious about this error message and looking for an explanation of what it means, and what the referenced "func-evals" are.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info:

```
FuncEval is, quite simply, the process of invoking a method while stopped in the debugger.
```

~ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/22/765986.aspx

The method can be invoked in different places in the VS IDE not exclusive to:

- immediate window
- watch window

Although I haven't found more info about the error message, it seems that I may have invoked a method in the code while in break mode and tried to detach from the process before that was completed, causing Visual Studio to prompt me to wait.